# Is client-server option is available in Wiremock.

Tags: wiremock

I am trying to validate server-client connectivity. I am running the client in one system and server in other system. When i manually running the Wiremock server in client system, i am able to see the responses from Server. My question here is "How to run the Wiremock Server in Server system via client System".

Comment: Can you elaborate on what it is that WireMock is doing? Is it proxying the messages from Client to Server, or is it stubbing both Client and Server?

Comment: It is stubbing the messages(request and response). Wiremock server which is running in standalone system / remote system provides the response. My requirement is to "Run the Wiremock in Server System via any automated way. So, that all my client System will get response". .